# Text[Multi-Level] Classification with many outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, classification

**Problem Statement:**

To classify a text document to which  category it belongs and also to classify up to two levels of the category.

**Sample Training Set:**

```
Description Category    Level1  Level2
The gun shooting that happened in Vegas killed two  Crime | High    Crime   High
Donald Trump elected as President of America    Politics | High Politics    High
Rian won in football qualifier  Sports | Low    Sports  Low
Brazil won in football final    Sports | High   Sports  High
```

**Initial Attempt:**

I tried to create a classifier model which would try to classify the Category using Random forest method and it gave me 90% overall.

**Code1:**

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from stemming.porter2 import stem

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

stop = stopwords.words('english')
data_file = "Training_dataset_70k"

#Reading the input/ dataset
data = pd.read_csv( data_file, header = 0, delimiter= "\t", quoting = 3, encoding = "utf8")
data = data.dropna()

#Removing stopwords, punctuation and stemming
data['Description'] = data['Description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
data['Description'] = data['Description'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ').replace('\s+',' ')
#data['Description'] = data['Description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([stem(word) for word in x.split()]))

train_data, test_data, train_label,  test_label = train_test_split(data.Description, data.Category, test_size=0.3, random_state=100)

RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_features = 40000, ngram_range = ( 1,3 ), sublinear_tf = True )
data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform( train_data )
RF.fit(data_features, train_label)
test_data_feature = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
Output_predict = RF.predict(test_data_feature)
print "Overall_Accuracy: " + str(np.mean(Output_predict == test_label))
with codecs.open("out_Category.txt", "w", "utf8") as out:
    for inp, pred, act in zip(test_data, Output_predict, test_label):
        try:
            out.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(inp, pred, act))
        except:
            continue
```

**Problem:**

I want to add two more level to the model they are Level1 and Level2 the reasons for adding them is when I ran classification for Level1 alone I got 96% accuracy. I am stuck at splitting training and test dataset and to train a model which has three classifications.

Is it possible to create a model with three classification or should I create three models? How to split train and test data?

**Edit1:**
    import string
    import codecs
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from stemming.porter2 import stem

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


stop = stopwords.words('english')

data_file = "Training_dataset_70k"
#Reading the input/ dataset
data = pd.read_csv( data_file, header = 0, delimiter= "\t", quoting = 3, encoding = "utf8")
data = data.dropna()
#Removing stopwords, punctuation and stemming
data['Description'] = data['Description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
data['Description'] = data['Description'].str.replace('[^\w\s]',' ').replace('\s+',' ')

train_data, test_data, train_label,  test_label = train_test_split(data.Description, data[["Category", "Level1", "Level2"]], test_size=0.3, random_state=100)
RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_features = 40000, ngram_range = ( 1,3 ), sublinear_tf = True )
data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform( train_data )
print len(train_data), len(train_label)
print train_label
RF.fit(data_features, train_label)
test_data_feature = vectorizer.transform(test_data)
#print test_data_feature
Output_predict = RF.predict(test_data_feature)
print "BreadCrumb_Accuracy: " + str(np.mean(Output_predict == test_label))
with codecs.open("out_bread_crumb.txt", "w", "utf8") as out:
    for inp, pred, act in zip(test_data, Output_predict, test_label):
        try:
            out.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(inp, pred, act))
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Could you clarify what are the two levels supposed to be? In the sample training set that you provided, your category is something like "Crime | High", and then your levels are just the first and the second word in the category (so it doesn't provide any new information).  Also, just to make sure- the category always consists of two words?

Comment: @MiriamFarber yes category always contains two words separated by pipe. The reason for adding level1 and level2 is I am getting higher accuracy for level1 so it would reduce the downward process even if category is wrong.

Comment: OK so just to make sure- when you run the model with one target you get 90% sucess if this target is the category column, and you get 96% sucess if this target is the level 1 column, and you want to construct a model where you have 3 targets (which are the three columns corresponding to description, level 1 and level 2), right?

Comment: Slight change description is the input and the target values are category, level1,level2. Other than that everything you said is right.

Comment: On a side note, I suggest to change your RF parameters (ex: increase the number of estimators)

Comment: @nbeuchat yes I actually do that my current number of estimator is 10.

Comment: @The6thSense oki, you might want to have a look at the model selection GridSearchCV to optimize them. Might be helpful: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: @nbeuchat Thanks for the links and Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scikit-learn Random Forest Classifier natively supports multiple outputs (see [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_random_forest_regression_multioutput.html)). Therefore, you do not need to create three separate models.

From the documentation of [RandomForestClassifier.fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit), the inputs to `fit` functions are:

> X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>
> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]

Therefore, you need an array `y` (your labels) of size N x 3 as your input to your RandomForestClassifier. In order to split your training and test set, you can do:

```
train_data, test_data, train_label,  test_label = train_test_split(data.Description, data[['Category','Level 1','Level 2']], test_size=0.3, random_state=100)
```

Your `train_label` and `test_label` should be arrays of size N x 3 that you can use to fit your model compare your predictions (NB: I have not tested it here, you might need to do some transposes).

Comment: I will check this with my program and will let you know

Comment: I am extremely sorry I haven't tried it yet and I am not close to my system. I will surely check it tomorrow and will let you know as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: @The6thSense No problem at all! Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi there I am getting the following error `ValueError: could not convert string to float` when calling `Output_predict = RF.predict(test_data_feature)` I also tried printing test_data_feature but it only show numeric value after conversion?.

Comment: @The6thSense Hello, did the ? `RF.fit` work? `RF.fit` and `RF.predict` expect numerical arrays as inputs. Your `data_features` is a numerical array but not the `train_label` and `test_label`. I forgot to make the transformation in my answer. 

I'll try to find some time to add this transformation to my answer. You can have a look at `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` and `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`

Did the version you posted in the question worked, executing without errors?

Comment: The version I posted worked perfectly with no error I just made changes to take additional output labels like you pointed.RF.FIT worked !! thats what bugs me I have added the actual code after your suggestion. Please look and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153474/discussion-between-the6thsense-and-nbeuchat).